# If item in list meets condition, remove item and multiple preceding items

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I am looking for a way to remove every ***nth*** item (let's call that item `i`) in a list, *and* also  ***x*** number of items directly preceding `i` in the list, if `i` meets a condition.

I have been looking around at list comprehensions and iterations but it has been tricky for a novice to find a solution.

Example:

```
myList = ["you", "are", "right", "I", "am", "wrong"]
```

For every *3rd* item, check if `i == "wrong"`:
If so, remove `i` and the *two* *(2)* items *preceding* `i`.

Effect: The sequence `"I, "am", "wrong"` is deleted from the list.

Comment: What should happen if `"wrong"` occurs at the beginning of the list, or if two `"wrong"`s occur with fewer than two items between them?

Comment: And... you think we're here to write that for you?

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for asking! That will never happen – in my example you can only find `"right"` and `"wrong"` on the 3rd location. And since three items are deleted if condition is met, it stays that way. But for future readers not bound to this rule, the order of the list should be considered.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Your comment only makes sense if you know *how* to write it. For the uninitiated, it's hard to know if the solution is easily achieved or requires *"significant"* multi-step work. Judging by your tone, I'm assuming it passes that threshold according to your definition?

Comment: So you think about it, and you try it, and you find out. SO isn't a tutorial service, that simply doesn't scale. *"I'm assuming it passes that threshold according to your definition?"* - I don't know what threshold you mean.

Comment: @jonrsharpe You just repeated the essence of your first comment. How does a beginner know exactly what's "tutorial" and what's operational?

Comment: Well you didn't seem to get it first time around. Do you mean the threshold between *"easily achieved"* and *"multi-step work"*? And which side of that would be *"passes"*? It's irrelevant which side it's on for the purposes of whether this is a good SO question (see [ask]), as either way you haven't actually shown what you've written and where you got stuck, but FWIW I'd say the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> myList = ["you", "are", "right", "I", "am", "wrong"]
>>> for i, l in enumerate(myList):
...   if l == 'wrong':
...     myList = myList[:i-2]
...     break
... 
>>> myList
['you', 'are', 'right']
```

Of course you could make 2 a variable

Comment: I believe your code works only if the list's length is a multiple of 3 and the only checked value that is 'wrong' is the **last** one.

Comment: I think it finds the first occurrence of 'wrong' which could be specified as a variable for some other string, and then takes a slice of everything from the start up to 2 values before 'wrong' position.  I agree it isn't robust, but it solves the OP's question.  He stated that his list is guarantied to have the requisite number of items before the trigger string.

Comment: Thanks Joel. I ended up using this, because the syntax was easier for me to understand and also was implementable into my "real-world" problem with some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

How about, for your example,

```
new_list = [v for i, v in enumerate(myList)
            if myList[3*int(i/3)+2] != 'wrong']
```

This works since you want to not-copy the entire group of 3 items that ends with 'wrong'. It would be more complicated if you wanted to delete only part of that group or some items not in that group. If, for example, you wanted to delete the 'wrong' value and the value just before it, you could use

```
new_list = [v for i, v in enumerate(myList)
            if myList[3*(i/3)+2] != 'wrong' or i % 3 == 0]
```

Comment: Thanks Rory, this is probably the more universally robust answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with `numpy.delete`. `Numpy.delete` remove the elements with using the index. So you can find the corresponding match and delete the preceding ones as much you want.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: myList = ["you", "are", "right", "I", "am", "wrong"]
In [3]: for i,j in enumerate(myList):
    if j == 'wrong':
        out = np.delete(myList,[i-2,i-1,i]).tolist()
   ....:      
In [4]: out
Out[1]: ['you', 'are', 'right']
```

Comment: Thanks for the numpy suggestion, will evaluate it!